# How can I export variables of componentDidMount ( react/react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to export variable in class?
Do I need Rudux?
I want to use

```
import device_token from './xxx';
```

below is my previous code.

```
global.device_token = token
```

However, I don't like global variables.

I just export Stnig variable, which is device_token.
I must not change the devce_token, because, device_token is user's device's name.
So I don't want to use redux. redux state is changeable.
I need an immutable variable. and import the variable.

```
export class PushNotification extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SomeAPI.then((token: string) => {
     const device_token = token
  });

  ....
}
```

Do you have any idea? 
thanks.

Comment: what type of variable is this ? Or what purpose does the variable serve ? Is it a constant ? Is it something that determines the UI ?

Comment: the variable is stning(device_token).
I just send device_token to rails server.
I get the token from fileA.
and send device_token to rails server in fileB.

Comment: Then you may use Redux. That way you could use it throughout your app, in a more declarative way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want access to `device_token` in other React components. If that is the case, then Redux would work because it would provide a centralized state that all components can draw from. I suggest using Redux to store/modify `device_token`, something like:

```
export class PushNotification extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SomeAPI.then((token: string) => {
      this.props.setDeviceToken(token);
    });

....
}
```

Where `setDeviceToken` dispatches an action creator that is passed in through a container.